# Varnish Redirect domain root

Tags: varnish

With varnish, how can I redirect a domain root (e.x. http://mydomain.com/ ), but set a backend for everything else? (e.x. http://mydomain.com/everythingelse)

Answer (score 1):

You may just use next URL match in vcl_recv:

```
if (req.url == "/")
{
    #redirect actions
}
else
{
    set req.backend = somebackendname;
}
```